# Ideal data structure for Next Word Prediction in Java using n-grams

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to implement a next word predictor for a custom keyboard on Android.

The present approach involves calculating the N-grams and storing it as a `HashMap`. The sentences are the keys and frequency the value.

```
// NGram dictionary
Map<String, Integer> nGramMap = new HashMap();
```

Once a sequence of words comes in like
`W1 W2 W3 W4`, I'm searching for N-grams that start with `W1 W2 W3 W4` and `W2 W3 W4` and so on.

While it works well on small datasets, for big datasets, this map becomes huge ~3,65,000.
What could be an efficient data structure for both the n-gram creation and retrieval time of predictions.

We tried out using a Trie. The retrieval was very fast but creation was slow. And it consumed a lot of RAM.

Comment: what if you use Tree DS instead of hashmap? for fast searching tree would be a better approach !

Answer (score 2):

The possible Data Structure for `n-gram` could be

1. Hash table (you have used)
2. B+ tree
3. Ternary AVL Tree
4. Hybrid AVL Tree

In my opinion trees will be better for fast searching problems, for more details please see [this](http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-971/paper21.pdf).

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Will see if it's feasible to implement the other data structures.